# Escaping multiple layers of mixed quotes for a curl command executed inside a bash script

Tags: bash, curl, escaping

I have the following bash script that uses its arguments to hit a RESTful web service (via `curl`) and prints out both the curl request made as well as the response:

```
#! /bin/bash

# arguments:
# $1 - username
# $2 - password
#
# outputs:
# if the script exits with a non-zero status then something went wrong

# verify that we have all 6 required arguments and fail otherwise
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Required arguments not provided"
    exit 1
fi

# set the script arguments to meaningful variable names
username=$1
password=$2

# login and fetch a valid auth token
req='curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d ''{"username":"$username","password":"$password"}'' https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam'
resp=$(curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d ''{"username":"$username","password":"$password"}'' https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam)

# echo the request for troubleshooting
echo "req = $req"

if [ -z "$resp" ]; then
  echo "Login failed; unable to parse response"
  exit 1
fi

echo "resp = $resp"
```

When I run this I get:

```
$ sh myscript.sh myUser 12345@45678
curl: (3) Port number ended with '"'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 12345@45678"
100  1107  100  1093  100    14   2849     36 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2849
req = curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam
resp = HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request...(rest omitted for brevity)
```

Obviously, I'm not escaping the various layers of single- and double-quotes inside the curl statement correctly, as is indicated by outputs like:

> `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 12345@45678"`

and:

> `req = curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam`

where the username/password variables are not parsing.

In reality my script takes a lot more than 2 arguments, which is why I'm changing them to have meaningful variable names (such as `$username` instead of `$1`) so its more understandable and readable.

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? Thanks in advance!

#### Update

I tried the suggestion which turns the `req` into:

```
curl -k -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d "{'username':'myUser','password':'12345@45678'}" https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam
```

However this is still an illegal curl command and instead needs to be:

```
curl -k -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"username":"myUser","password":"12345@45678"}' https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam
```

Comment: First: do not try to store commands in variables; the shell parses quotes before expanding variables, so quotes in variables' values don't do anything useful. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Ahh, maybe the other way around then (storing variables in the commands themselves)? Interesting concept, although I'm having a tough time seeing the "forest through the trees" on the implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I said in a comment, storing commands in variables just doesn't work right. Variables are for data, not executable code. Second, you have two levels of quoting here: quotes that're part of the shell syntax (which are parsed, applied, and removed by the shell before the arguments are passed to `curl), and quotes that're part of the JSON syntax.

But the second problem is actually worse than that, because simply embedding an arbitrary string into some JSON may result in JSON syntax errors if the string contains characters that're part of JSON syntax. Which passwords are likely to do. To get the password (and username for that matter) embedded *correctly* in your JSON, use a tool that understands JSON syntax, like `jq`:

```
userinfo=$(jq -n -c --arg u "$username" --arg p "$password" '{"username":$u,"password":$p}')
```

Explanation: this uses `--arg` to set the `jq` variables `u` and `p` to the shell variables `$username` and `$password` respectively (and the double-quotes around the shell variables will keep the shell from doing anything silly to the values), and creates a JSON snippet with them embedded. `jq` will automatically add appropriate quoting/escaping/whatever is needed.

Then, to use it with `curl`, use something like this:

```
resp=$(curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$userinfo" https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam)
```

Again, the double-quotes around `$userinfo` keep the shell from doing anything silly. You should almost always put double-quotes around variables references in the shell.

Note that I never used the `req` variable to store the command. If you need to print the command (or its equivalent), use something like this:

```
printf '%q ' curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$userinfo" https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam
echo
```

The `%q` format specifier tells the shell to add appropriate quoting/escaping so that you could run the result as a shell command, and it'd work properly. (And the `echo` is there because `printf` doesn't automatically add a newline at the end of its output.)

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Davisson (+1) but when I try your example I get "`jq: error: u/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
{"username":u,"password":p}                      
jq: error: p/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
{"username":u,"password":p}   
`" any ideas?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup D'oh! The `jq` variables are `$u` and `$p`, not just `u` and `p`. I fixed that problem while I was testing my solution, but must've copied-and-pasted the before-fix version into my answer. I've corrected it; try the fixed version above.

Answer (score 1):

try changing this:

```
req='curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d ''{"username":"$username","password":"$password"}'' https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam'
```

to this

```
req="curl -k -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d \"{'username':'$username','password':'$password'}\" https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam"
```

and similarly for the **resp**

Comment: Thanks @vgersh99 (+1) -- I think you got me *closer* but still not quite there. Please see my update above ^^^ thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

ah those pesky "curly" thingies...
how 'bout...

```
req="curl -k -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{\"username\":\"$username\",\"password\":\"$password\"}' https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam"
```

Comment: Thanks again @vgersh99 (+1) so that fixes it for the `req` variable (thank you!!!) but when I attempt to make the same changes for the `resp` variable I get errors. Can you please include what I need to change `resp` to in your answer? Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 1):

This needs even more escaping:
With:

```
resp=$(curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$username\",\"password\":\"$password\"}" https://somerepo.example.com/flimflam)
```

In bash, the variables are still expanded when they're inside single quotes that are inside double quotes.
And you'll need the \" double quotes in the payload as per the JSON definition.

EDIT: I rerun the curl through a HTTP proxy and corrected the script line (see above, removed the single quotes). Results (in raw HTTP) are now:

```
POST /flimflam HTTP/1.1
Host: somerepo.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 44
Connection: close

{"username":"user","password":"12345@abcde"}
```

(which should be fine)

Comment: Thanks @lab9 (+1) but the curl is still failing execution. Using your changes I'm still getting `resp = HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request...` as echo output. However if I copy the curl printed by the `req`, and run that copied curl on the command line, it works and I get HTTP 200 OK.

Comment: ok. If you have the chance to troubleshoot, you could put a single line with _set -x_ above the "resp=$(...)" line and rerun the script. There will be additional debug output that might help. Also, you could have a look at the server logs (in case you control them)